# Can you make vue2-datepicker disregard timezone and always think in UTC?

Tags: vuejs2

My time comes back from the server as **2019-12-06T16:00:00.000Z**. vue2-datepicker keeps showing as 10am.

Can I make [vue2-datepicker](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker) disregard timezones so that it displays 4pm and also returns UTC when selecting a time? Out of the box when I set 10am it sends 4pm. I need it to send the time that I chose in the UI.

*I realize more information may be needed in order for you to help; if so, please comment and I will provide.*

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install moment --save
```

convert server time by moment and try this code:

```
<template>
    <div class="container" style="direction: ltr; margin-top: 100px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <date-picker2 v-model="date"
                              type="datetime"
                              format="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A"
                              valueType="format">
                </date-picker2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import DatePicker2 from 'vue2-datepicker';
    import 'vue2-datepicker/index.css';
    var moment = require('moment');

    export default {
        name: "test",
        data() {
            return {
                server_date_time: '2019-12-06T16:00:00.000Z',
                date: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            moment.locale('en');
            this.date = moment(this.server_date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A')
        },
        watch: {
            date() {
                console.log('date= ' + this.date);
            }
        },
        components: { DatePicker2 },
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```